# API Requests required to take a photo in Olympus Air OPC?

Tags: olympus-camerakit, olympus-air

Playing with the Olympus AIR A01 and I am trying to figure out the process to take a picture and store it on the SD card via URL.

I can connect to the WiFi, set mode to record, query the free space but when I run "exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake" I get the generic WiFi error.

Steps:

Check status:

```
/get_connectmode.cgi
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectmode>OPC</connectmode>
```

Set status:

```
/switch_cameramode.cgi?mode=rec
<?xml version="1.0"?><result>OK</result>
```

Get Status:

```
/get_state.cgi
<?xml version="1.0"?><response><cardstatus>normal</cardstatus>    <cardremainnum>1807</cardremainnum><cardremainsec>4786</cardremainsec><cardremainbyte>4294967295</cardremainbyte><lensmountstatus>normal</lensmountstatus><imagingstate>normal</imagingstate><focallength>8</focallength><widefocallength>8</widefocallength><telefocallength>8</telefocallength><electriczoom>NG</electriczoom><macrosetting>NG</macrosetting></response>
```

Attempt to take a pic:

```
/exec_takemotion.cgi?com=newstarttake
<?xml version="1.0"?><response><errorcode>0xB000</errorcode> 
<errormsg>WIFI_INTERNAL_ERROR</errormsg><dbgmsg>reserved</dbgmsg></response>
```

I must be missing something simple, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
-Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `/exec_takemisc.cgi?com=startliveview&port=5555` needs before `exec_takemotion.cgi`.

You can get a document about communication specifications from [OPC Hack & Make Project](http://opc.olympus-imaging.com/en/tools/toolssdk/communications/).

The section 7 in the document says:

1. Negotiation (Recording mode)
2. Normal Shooting
3. Switch Operation Mode (Playback mode)
4. Get Image